# Add file to HKEY_CURRENT_USER Autorun AND HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in only ONE script

Tags: vbscript

I have this VBScript:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\example"
WshShell.RegWrite myKey, "C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe", "REG_SZ"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

which adds

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe"

to the startup registry

> "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\example"

Now I also want to add

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe"

to the startup registry

> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\example"

How can you do that in only ONE SINGLE VBScript?

I tried to just modify this code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\example"
WshShell.RegWrite myKey, "C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe", "REG_SZ"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

so that it would add the program to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and then paste it underneath, but that didn't work.

Comment: You've tagged this `vbscript` but you say it's executed as a `vba` script.  Can you specify which it is clearly, as `vba` and `vbscript` are two different things.

Comment: i thought its the same? i meant to say visual basic script

Comment: `VBA` is Visual Basic for Applications (usually found by accessing the IDE within MS Office tools such as Excel), and `VBScript` is a scripting language.  They have similar roots but they are not the same thing, no.

Comment: Are you running the script under an administrator account?

Comment: Yes I do run it as admin

Comment: For one thing, your 2 scripts are identical. None of them writes to HKLM. Also, remove `On Error Resume Next` from your code, so that you can actually see what goes wrong.

Comment: "Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\example"
WshShell.RegWrite myKey, "C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe", "REG_SZ"
Set WshShell = Nothing" would write to HKLM right?

Comment: Yes. But the code in your question says `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` in both cases.

Comment: You also need to be an admin to write to HKLM.

Comment: @user10081932 Remove the `On Error Resume Next` and run it to see what the actual error is. At the moment if the script errors it will be skipped without anything being reported. If you are going to use `OERN` at least check for errors using `If Err.Number <> 0 Then ... End If`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim wshShell
    Dim myKey

    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    myKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\example"

    wshShell.RegWrite myKey, "C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe", "REG_SZ"
```